# PHP echo function is not outputing strings in the format '<something.somethong_else>'

Tags: php

PHP echo function is not outputing strings in the format of html tag like `<something.   somethong_else>`, may  be because it is like HTML tags, is there any way to display it?

`echo 'hi<h.i>';`

Eg : this displays as

echo 'hi';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encode the string if you what the text to appear

```
echo htmlentities("hi<h.i>");
```

Answer (score 2):

try using

```
<?php
echo htmlentities('hi<h.i>');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a thing called HTML. Where strings in `<something.somethong_else>` format have some meaning. Go figure.

Comment: i need to display stdio.h or iostream.h just like we use in c or cpp, thanx for reply :)

Comment: the question acknowledged the similarity with HTML. why the need for sarcasm?

Comment: it is worded as "PHP echo function is not outputting" which is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 1):

PHP can echo out tags.

Example

```
<?php
  echo '<p>Hello World</p>';
?>
```

Keep in mind, the PHP will echo where it is called. So you can also do this

```
<p>
<?php echo 'Hello World'; ?>
</p>
```

UPDATE

Since new information is sent. You can make `< into &lt; and > into &gt;` Look at HTML entities.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use `htmlentities()`, try this:

```
echo htmlentities('hi<h.i>');
```